# Clarification in Sql Query

Tags: sql, oracle, sybase

I have a clarification the way in which I'm suppose to query.

I'm suppose to get the records which lie within a particular time range.

I have a record in table **A** which has the start time as **1900-01-01 21:00:00.0**    and endTime as **1900-01-01 22:00:00.0**

And I have another table **B** which has the startTime as **1900-01-01 21:47:43.0** and endTime as **1900-01-01 21:47:48.0**

Now my task is to find all the entries in table A which has the startTime and endTime of table B.

Initially I used as query as follows:

```
select *
from A
where startTime between '1900-01-01 21:47:43.0' and '1900-01-01 21:47:48.0'
```

and I got no results.

And then I tried the following query

```
select *
from A
where startTime < '1900-01-01 21:47:43.0' and startTime > '1900-01-01 21:47:48.0'
```

and I got one row.

In the table A I have ranges like:

```
1900-01-01 21:00:00.0 - 1900-01-01 22:00:00.0
1900-01-01 22:00:00.0 - 1900-01-01 23:00:00.0
1900-01-01 23:00:00.0 - 1900-01-01 23:30:00.0
.
.
.
```

and so on.

And in table B I have rows start and endTimes like

```
1900-01-01 21:27:30.0 - 1900-01-01 21:27:55.0
1900-01-01 22:11:22.0 - 1900-01-01 22:11:44.0
1900-01-01 23:22:11.0 - 1900-01-01 23:22:55.0
.
.
.
and so on.
```

And I have to take the startTime and endTime from table B and match the slot in table A and get the results.

So is my first way of querying correct or is the second way correct or is there any other way to do this.

**Edit**

Since we are trying to find the records in table A where there exists a range I tried to use the start and endTimes of B as following:

```
select *
    from A
        and '1900-01-01 21:47:43.0' between startTime and endTime
        and '1900-01-01 21:47:48.0' between startTime and endTime
```

Comment: It depends on what you want the result to be, do you want the start and end times to match between the two tables? Or do you want to find records in B that are within the ranges from table A?

Comment: @Goat_CO: I want all the the records on table A which encapsulates both the startTime and the endTime of the record in Table B. In this case what am I suppose to do.

Comment: It's confusing because at the top of your question you show values for A that are different than the values for A at the bottom, and values for B at the top that are different than the values for B at the bottom.

Comment: @Goat_co: I'm sorry I had the values mixed up.I have corrected the values. So how do I find all the the records on table A which encapsulates both the startTime and the endTime of the record in Table B. In this case what am I suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing would be to JOIN the tables using BETWEEN

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
JOIN B
ON b.start_time BETWEEN a.start_time AND a.end_time
AND b.end_time BETWEEN a.start_time AND a.end_time
```

That will return everything from A where both start and end times from B are encapsulated by a range in A.

Your second query doesn't quite look right, since you're comparing the start_time on both sides, but that idea is similar as this:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
JOIN B
ON a.start_time < b.start_time
AND a.end_time > b.end_time
```

Either query should return the ranges from A that encapsulate start-end times from B.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here your second query is returning one row but your first query where you have joined the 2 table return no rows.

Comment: Here your second query is returning one row but your first query where you have joined the 2 table return no rows coz A's start time `1900-01-01 21:00:00` does not occur between `1900-01-01 21:47:43.0` and `1900-01-01 21:47:48.0` and A's endTime `1900-01-01` does not occur between `1900-01-01 21:47:43.0` and `1900-01-01 21:47:48.0`. So how to correct the first query.

Comment: A is the table with the ranges, right?  The first query says the start_time of b has to be between the ranges of A, and the end_time of b has to be between the ranges of A, fully encapsulated.  if the ranges are in A that should be working.

Comment: Yes A is the table with ranges. Since we are trying to find the records in table A where there exists a range I tried to use the start and endTimes of B and I have edited the question which has the new query. Can you check if its consistent. I think your second query and the new edited one by me are the same.